# Card Force Trick. How to complete the perfect shuffle or riffle shuffle

Tags: java, for-loop, intellij-idea, indexoutofboundsexception

I have completed nearly all of the java code for the perfect shuffle. I am just struggling with the error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 26 out of bounds for length 26 at cards_shuffle.main(cards_shuffle.java:72)" This error refers to the line:

```
Output:
```

Top Half of the Shuffled Deck:

4 of Spades
10 of Diamonds
8 of Spades
Ace of Diamonds
4 of Hearts
Jack of Hearts
Queen of Hearts
Queen of Spades
4 of Diamonds
Jack of Spades
King of Hearts
5 of Hearts
10 of Hearts
9 of Spades
2 of Clubs
6 of Spades
King of Diamonds
3 of Clubs
7 of Spades
Jack of Diamonds
3 of Hearts
7 of Diamonds
3 of Diamonds
9 of Hearts
Ace of Clubs
5 of Diamonds

Bottom Half of the Shuffled Deck:

6 of Hearts
7 of Hearts
10 of Clubs
Ace of Hearts
2 of Hearts
Queen of Diamonds
6 of Clubs
8 of Diamonds
King of Spades
5 of Spades
Queen of Clubs
9 of Clubs
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
9 of Diamonds
Ace of Spades
10 of Spades
King of Clubs
7 of Clubs
2 of Diamonds
6 of Diamonds
4 of Clubs
8 of Hearts
5 of Clubs
8 of Clubs
Jack of Clubs

Card Shuffle:

6 of Hearts

```
I have just included the 6 of Hearts once but it prints out 52 times.

Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: I assume you got confused with the loops, I proposed a solution below, let me know if it helped you or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` variable exceeds the array bounds of `top_half`, since it is incremented in inner loop for `bottom_half.length` times. 
Also, you should not increment variable `i` at all, since you want to fill card force from top to bottom. Otherwise you should use separate index for it.

Try

```
int i = top_half.length - 1;
int j = bottom_half.length - 1;
int index = 51;
while (index >= 0) {
    card_force[index--] = top_half[i--];
    card_force[index--] = bottom_half[j--];
}
```

Comment: Thank  you so much for the help. Trying out your solution, the program now prints out the first item in the bottom_half 52 times. I will keep trying with the program to see if I can resolve it.

Comment: @NaomiReynolds you mean, the card_force[] filled only by copies of first item of bottom_half?

Comment: @NaomiReynolds can you please give me the full output of the program?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, the 6 of hearts (which is the first item in the bottom half) is produced 52 times in the output.

Comment: I have edited the post to show you the current code

Comment: @NaomiReynolds it looks like in your last loop, where you output the card force, you are using `card_force[pr]`, change it to `card_force[i]` since your loop increments and uses `i`. However you can on the other hand just change the loop to `for(int pr = 0; pr < card_force.length; pr++)` to update output value, now it is always first element of card_force

Comment: @NaomiReynolds the problem is not on the side of proposed solution, you can fix it like I proposed in comment above. Let me know, if it helped you or it did not

Comment: @NaomiReynolds I am glad it helped. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it was useful for you :)